# Configuration of IBMMQ with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am doing an IBM WebSphere MQ testing using JMeter. I have created the JSR223 sampler script based on the following reference link https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how. Here i am using only one queue name(request) to inject my request into IBM MQ server.

But in my cases, i have to retrieve my response using different query name.
Example :
Request_queryname : DNB.LX.SRXX.LOGGING.IN
Response_queryname : DNB.LX.SRXX.LOGGING.OUT

So if i am passing my request using this query name "DNB.LX.SRXX.LOGGING.IN", i need to retrive my response with another query name "DNB.LX.SRXX.LOGGING.OUT".

May i know how to retrieve this response. I am having following parameters with me.

QueueManager : CLDACESP
Channelname : ACE.CONFIG.SXXCONN
Hostname : 172.25.XX.XX
Host port : 1414
queue name(request) :DNB.LX.SRXX.LOGGING.IN
queue name(response) :DNB.LX.SRXX.LOGGING.OUT

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new session pointing to another queue, all you need to do is to duplicate the code and change the queue name.

I.e.

Producer:

```
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants

import javax.jms.Session

def hostName = "172.25.XX.XX"
def hostPort = 1414
def channelName = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN"
def queueManagerName = "QM1"
def queueName = "DNB.LX.SRXX.LOGGING.IN"

def ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER)
def cf = ff.createConnectionFactory()

cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, hostPort)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channelName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManagerName)

def conn = cf.createConnection("app", "test")
def sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)

def destination = sess.createQueue(queueName)

conn.start()

def producer = sess.createProducer(destination)

def rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())

def payload = String.format("JMeter...IBM MQ...test message no. %09d!", rnd.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
def msg = sess.createTextMessage(payload)

producer.send(msg)


producer.close()
```

Consumer:

```
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants

import javax.jms.Session

def hostName = "172.25.XX.XX"
def hostPort = 1414
def channelName = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN"
def queueManagerName = "QM1"
def queueName = "DNB.LX.SRXX.LOGGING.OUT"

def ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER)
def cf = ff.createConnectionFactory()

cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, hostPort)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channelName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManagerName)

def conn = cf.createConnection("app", "test")
def sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)

conn.start()

def consumer = sess.createConsumer(destination)

def msg = consumer.receive(1)

//do what you need with this message(s)

consumer.close()
```

More information:

- [IBMMQ Classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=jms-mq-classes)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. I will try this step and confirm you back.